# Install redis-cli only on CentOS

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, centos

How can I install redis-cli only on CentOS, I know how to do it on ubuntu "sudo apt-get install redis-tools" but looking for similar package for CentOS.

Comment: CentOS 7 : The package `redis` provides redis-cli . **Repo** : "gitforge-pagure" http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.9.2009/infra/x86_64/gitforge-pagure/ ....  or OpenStack https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/environment-packages-rdo.html ..... Or just download redis, and install with `yum install ./redis-3.2.12-2.el7.x86_64.rpm`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using amzn linux 2:

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
sudo yum update
sudo yum install redis
```

Answer (score 2):

I am familiar with this approach:

```
wget http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
tar xvzf redis-stable.tar.gz
cd redis-stable
make
cp src/redis-cli /usr/local/bin/
chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/redis-cli
```

as you can see above, here you have to compile the source code using make. You hence need to make sure that you have c compiler on your OS. If you do not, then this can help you:

```
sudo yum install gcc
```

**Also be aware,** that this approach will also create another executables in src/ folder. I recommend you to check this out [here](https://redis.io/topics/quickstart).

hope it helped, have a nice day!